# Extract a name after certain string

Tags: python, regex

I am quite new to Python (3.9) but with everything available online I thought I might be able to solve a problem.

I am trying to extract a person's name from an invoice, which may be 2-3 consecutive words at any length and may rarely contain a hyphen.

```
Phone: (111) 311-1111
Desired Name:   Friday twk-test Date of Birth:   01/01/1988
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
(?<=Desired Name:\s{3}[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+
```

Match:

```
riday twk
```

The output needs to be:

```
Friday twk-test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\bDesired Name:\s*([^\W\d_]+(?:[\s-]+[^\W\d_]+){1,2})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5DVD08/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `Desired Name:` - a literal string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^\W\d_]+(?:[\s-]+[^\W\d_]+){1,2})` - Group 1: two or three words consisting of only Unicode letters that are separated with one or more whitespaces or hyphens:

  - `[^\W\d_]+` - one or more Unicode letters
  - `(?:[\s-]+[^\W\d_]+){1,2}` - one or two sequences of:

    - `[\s-]+` - one or more whitespaces or `-` chars
    - `[^\W\d_]+` - one or more Unicode letters.

If there can be a single whitespace or hyphen, remove `+` after `[\s-]`.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/lem7pU):

```py
import re
text="Phone: (111) 311-1111\nDesired Name:   Friday twk-test Date of Birth:   01/01/1988"
pattern=r"\bDesired Name:\s*([^\W\d_]+(?:[\s-]+[^\W\d_]+){1,2})"
match = re.search(pattern, text)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
# => Friday twk-test
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of your invoices follow this same structure, then you can use this regex:

```
\bDesired Name:\s*([A-Za-z\s\-]+?(?=\s+Date of Birth))
```

A demo is here: [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/SclKyH/1)

What this does is:

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `Desired Name:`: string to match that we know is before the name
- `\s*`: match zero or more whitespaces
- `([A-Za-z\s\-]+?(?=\s+Date of Birth))`: A capturing group to match the name

  - `[A-Za-z\s\-]+`: match any letter (either upper or lower case), as well as whitespace and hyphens.
  - `?(?=\s+Date of Birth)`: positive lookahead, so it will match everything up until this string.

What this means is that if someone's first name and last name both have a hyphen, and they also have another name, the entire name will be captured.